# Looping through an object and displaying input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, loops

I have a javascript object that consists of two arrays. We can call one array adaptors and the other barcodes. The adaptors array will always have 8 strings, while the barcodes will always have 3 strings but may have up to 8 strings. Ok, so I need to display the adaptor string, the barcode string and than have a input field for the user to enter another string(barcode). However, I need to find the length of the barcodes array and than only display that many input fields. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? jQuery, Angular?

```
var bar = {
    “adaptors”: ["506-707", "502-701", "501-708", "507-706", "508-704", "505-703", "503-705", "504-702" ],
    “barcodes”:["11-11-1111","11-11-2222","11-11-3333","11-11-4444"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Only inputs for the remaining barcodes spaces? For instance if your barcodes array had a length of 5, you would only want to add/display 3 inputs? Or if its length is 3 only show 3?

Comment: This is correct, so the length of the barcodes array would be how many input fields are displayed.

Comment: you can do it with angularJS, updating answer

Comment: thats what I'm trying now, ng-repeat="(adptors, barcodes) in barcodes" gets me close but not all the way there, I'm new with angular.js

Answer (score 1):

try this angularJS code, here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/3144/)

view

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="(index,val) in bar.adaptors">
 {{val}} <input type="text" ng-show="bar.barcodes[index]">
</div>
</div>
```

controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.bar = {
      adaptors: ["506-707", "502-701", "501-708", "507-706", "508-704", "505-703", "503-705", "504-702" ],
    barcodes:["11-11-1111","11-11-2222","11-11-3333","11-11-4444"]
 }
}
```

Comment: This code was enough to push me in the correct direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each adaptor correlates with each barcode meaning `adaptors[0]` lines up with `barcodes[0]`:

You can use an ng-repeat with `(index,value)` and use `index` or use the auto generated `$index` value that is set each iteration to access the `bar.barcodes` element. Use `ng-if` to only generate the input if the array element exists.

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller("ctrl",["$scope",function($scope){
  $scope.bar = {
    "adaptors": ["506-707", "502-701", 
                 "501-708", "507-706", 
                 "508-704", "505-703", 
                 "503-705", "504-702" ],
    "barcodes":["11-11-1111","11-11-2222","11-11-3333","11-11-4444"]
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="adaptor in bar.adaptors">
    <th>Adaptor</th><td>{{adaptor}}</td>
    <th>Barcode</th><td>
       <input ng-if="bar.barcodes[$index]" ng-model="bar.barcodes[$index]">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```